# Как сделать в установщике так чтобы программа устанавливалась на панель задач?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Сделал проект и теперь мне нужно сделать для него установщик. Но вот какая проблема. Мне нужно чтобы exe файл(запуск программы) программы устанавливался на панель задач. Может кто с таким сталкивался и знают решение. Я делаю через Visual Studio 2022 и использую расширение Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project. Подскажите как решить такую проблему, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159451/how-to-pin-an-application-to-the-taskbar/57160775#57160775

Comment: @Виктор прошу прощения , это точно поможет?

Comment: @FarKane что мешает узнать это самостоятельно?

Comment: @aepot да то что я открывал эту ссылку уже давно и она мне не подходила. Вы не знаете как сделать чтобы программа устанавливалась в панель задач?

Comment: Нет, мне это никогда не надо было, к тому же принято что панель задач - область юзера, каждый крепит туда что хочет. Есть главное меню и рабочий стол для значков

Comment: @aepot просто яндекс при установке ставит автоматически свой значок в панель задач. И я не пойму как они это делают. А мне нужно именно так.

Comment: И это жутко бесит, ага.